# Working with dictionaries, how would you find/track duplicate GUIDs given this list?

Tags: python, dictionary, guid

I work a lot with WiX XML files and just about every object in WiX requires a GUID.  To avoid copy-paste errors, I've set about on a way to sort and display all duplicate GUIDs given a list like this (created with `find` and `egrep`):

```
./A2.Spam.EggsMgrSvc/__A2.Spam.EggsMgrSvc.wixproj:3A206536-FBCC-4911-AF2B-CBCD76E2C23E
./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/Files.wxs:1F372E8A-95B9-49AC-84A6-998E7F5B0689
./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/Files.wxs:4BB4FBAD-032A-4FBA-8B81-8AA2876E6765
./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/File1.wxs:E289D834-4421-4DCE-B0A8-94C09978058A
./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/Files.wxs:083863F1-70DE-11D0-BD40-00A0C911CE86
./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/File1.wxs:E289D834-4421-4DCE-B0A8-94C09978058A
./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/Files.wxs:083863F1-70DE-11D0-BD40-00A0C911CE86
./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/File2.wxs:E289D834-4421-4DCE-B0A8-94C09978058A
```

in a format like this:

```
  3 E289D834-4421-4DCE-B0A8-94C09978058A
       2 ./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/File1.wxs
       1 ./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/File2.wxs
  2 083863F1-70DE-11D0-BD40-00A0C911CE86
       2 ./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/Files.wxs
```

The total number of occurences of the GUID are counted next to the GUID, then the number of occurences of that GUID are counted in each file.

I've come up with the following script (which produced the above output).  I'm still new to Python and am really trying to understand dictionaries and their practical uses.  Was using nested dictionaries the right way to go?  I picked dictionaries because I thought it was the easiest way to add/track unique entries.  Though, using syntax like `parent_dict['child_dict_key']['value_key']` feels a bit odd, like maybe I could make use of `items()` or other iterable methods/techniques:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

guids = {}
f_and_g = open( 'files-and-guids.txt', 'r')

for fg in f_and_g.readlines():
    fname, guid = map( str.strip, fg.split(':') )

    if guid not in guids:
        guids[guid] = { 'count': 1, 'files': {} }
    else:
        guids[guid]['count'] += 1

    ## Count how many times a GUID was used in a given file
    if fname not in guids[guid]['files']:
        guids[guid]['files'][fname]  = 1
    else:
        guids[guid]['files'][fname] += 1

## Sort by total count for a given GUID
for guid in sorted( guids, key=lambda x:guids[x]['count'], reverse=True):
    ## Skip printing if count is below threshold
    if guids[guid]['count'] < 2:
        continue
    guid_dict = guids[guid]
    print '{:>3} {}'.format( guid_dict['count'], guid )
    ## Sort by filename counts
    for fname in sorted( guid_dict['files'],
                         key=lambda x: guid_dict['files'][x], reverse=True ):
        fname_cnt = guid_dict['files'][fname]
        print '{:>8} {}'.format( fname_cnt, fname)
```

Comment: the question might be more appropriate at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, I think it would, too.  I'll go there next time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another variation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

# count guids
perfile = defaultdict(Counter)
total = Counter()
for line in fileinput.input():
    fname, guid = map(str.strip, line.split(':'))
    perfile[guid][fname] += 1
    total[guid] += 1

# print most common guid first
for guid, count in total.most_common():
    if count < 2: continue # skip printing if count is below threshold
    print '{:>3} {}'.format(count, guid)
    # sorting by filename counts
    for fname, fname_cnt in perfile[guid].most_common():
        print '{:>8} {}'.format(fname_cnt, fname)
```

#### Example

```
$ python2.7 count-guid.py  input 
  3 E289D834-4421-4DCE-B0A8-94C09978058A
       2 ./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/File1.wxs
       1 ./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/File2.wxs
  2 083863F1-70DE-11D0-BD40-00A0C911CE86
       2 ./A2.Spam.TrojanBunnies/Files/Files.wxs
```

Don't overthink it if the script is clear and it works for you.

Comment: +1 for making it even simpler. And I also agree that the OP's version isn't so horrible either, although these are good improvements.

Comment: Thank you, I picked this answer for its succinctness. I tried making my own "Counter()", which is in my answer below, but ended up paying penalty for all the `len()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it something like this, although I haven't actually tested this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections
import operator

guids = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
f_and_g = open('files-and-guids.txt', 'r')

for fg in f_and_g:
    fname, guid = map(str.strip, fg.split(':'))

    guids[guid][fname] += 1

## Sort by total count for a given GUID

guids_counts_totals = [(guids, counts, sum(counts.itervalues()))
                       for guids, counts
                       in guids.iteritems()]

guids_counts_totals_sorted = sorted(guids_counts_totals,
                                    key=operator.itemgetter(2),
                                    reverse=True)

for guid, counts, total in guids_counts_totals_sorted:
    ## Skip printing if count is below threshold
    if total < 2:
        continue

    print '{:>3} {}'.format(total, guid)

    ## Sorting by filename counts
    fnames_counts_sorted = sorted(counts.iteritems(),
                                  key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    for fname, count in fnames_counts_sorted:
        print '{:>8} {}'.format(count, fname)
```

Some changes here:

- Use of `collections.defaultdict` and `collections.Counter` instead of repeatedly checking for presence of a key and setting it to 1 if it's not there
- Not duplicating data by storing a count for each GUID and for each filename. You can just sum up all the counts for each filename of a GUID
- Sorting and iterating over `dict.itervalues()` instead of just using keys and then looking up their values
- Use of `operator.itemgetter()` instead of `lambda` expressions
- Spacing according to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I especially agreed with not duplicating the counts which was half of the inspiration for trying my answer below. P.S., there's a misspelling in your code: `iteemgetter(2)` should be `itemgetter(2)`. I don't have edit rights, and SO wants at least 6 characters changed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of the answers I tried again, shying away from any other libs for the sake of just trying to make my life more difficult:

```
def MyCounter(l):
    d = dict()
    for i in l:
        if i not in d:
            d[i] = 1
        else:
            d[i] += 1
    return d

def main():
    guids = dict()
    f_and_g = open('files-and-guids.txt', 'r')
    for fg in f_and_g.readlines():
        fname, guid = map(str.strip, fg.split(':'))
        if guid not in guids:
            guids[guid] = [fname]
        else:
            guids[guid] += [fname]

    ## Sort by total count for a given GUID
    for guid in sorted(guids, key=lambda guid: len(guids[guid]), reverse=True):
        ## Skip printing if count is below threshold
        if len(guids[guid]) < 2: continue
        guid_list = guids[guid]
        print '{:>3} {}'.format( len(guid_list), guid )
        ## Sort by filename counts
        counts = MyCounter(guid_list)
        for fname, fname_cnt in sorted(counts.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1],
                                   reverse=True):
            print '{:>8} {}'.format(fname_cnt, fname)
```